# @Override on interface methods Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, overriding

These are my settings:

[image]

I am using Java 6, why do I get errors when I uses @Override on interface methods?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to explain what kind of errors you get.

Comment: The method onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long) of type new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){} must override a superclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there are no project-specific settings that are overriding your defaults. Sometimes, particularly when importing projects, Eclipse will assign a project-specific setting that is less than 1.6.

Comment: It is not imported, but it was actually set to 1.5 on that specific project, I wonder why! Anyway, I selected 1.7 and now a get a new error "Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties." If I fix project properties, it rolls back to 1.5 again :/

Answer (score 1):

change your compiler compliance level to 1.6 can help you

Answer (score 1):

That is an Eclipse preference, under Java / Compiler / "Errors/Warnings". In the Annotations section, there is a preference for Missing Override annotations.

Comment: The project can override the IDE settings. Check there too. Project / Properties